# Split a string at ";" with php

Tags: php, string, split, preg-split

I have a string called `$gallery`, `$gallery` is a list of image URLS The image urls are seperated by a semi- colon `;`. Example

```
http://www.website.com/image1.jpg;http://www.website.com/image2.jpg;http://www.website.com/image3.jpg
```

How can I split this up and place each url in an image tag, I suppose using preg_split?

Thanks

Comment: Note that separating URL's with ';' is a bad idea, as semicolon can be part of a URL. In fact any special character can in principle occur in a URL, so avoid gluing together URL's in one string altogether if you can. Other than that, yes, explode() works fine for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need preg_split for this.

```
$urls = explode(';', $string);
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    echo '<img src="'.$url.'" />';
}
```

Comment: `echo '<img src="'.htmlspecialchars($url).'" />';`

Answer (score 4):

No need for regular expressions with `preg_split()`, just a simple regex-less `explode()` will do since they're delimited by a semicolon.

```
foreach (explode(';', $gallery) as $url) {
    echo '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES) . '" alt="" />';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use str_replace

```
'<img src="' . str_replace(';','" /><img src="',$gallery) . '" />';
```